# Trim string at first punctuation character excluding white space

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a way to trim a string at the first instance of a punctuation character that isn't a space.

Thanks

[EDIT]
I have tried the following:

```
var length = input.IndexOf(@"[^\w\s]");

return input.Substring(0, length);
```

Comment: And what do you mean with "Trim at a certain char" ? Trim happens at the ens, at a char-position you can split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "Hello, world!";
string t = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => !Char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Char.IsPunctuation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3ahtyy.aspx).  Then just substring to the index.